Using Conditional Statements in Dymola
I'm new on Dymola and I can't manage to get this code running. I'm trying to create a random generation to simulate the number of people in a room.
Here is the code I have so far. Do you have any idea what could be the problem ?
model Trial

  Real p(start=rand()/32767);
  Real E(start=1);

equation 

when (sample(1,3600)) then//sample(start+interval) ce qui donne "start + i*interval"
    p = rand()/32767;

    if E == 1 then
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 2;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 3;
      else
        E = 4;
      end if;

    elseif E == 2 then
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 1;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 3;
      else
        E = 4;
      end if;

    elseif E == 3 then
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 1;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 2;
      else
        E = 4;
      end if;

    elseif E == 4 then
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 1;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 2;
      else
        E = 3;
      end if;
    end if;

end when;

  annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)), Diagram(
        coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)),
    experiment(StopTime=86400, __Dymola_Algorithm="Dassl"));
end Trial;



I would suggest you have a look at Modelica.Math.Random.Examples.GenerateRandomNumbers. Based on this example, I ended up with:
model Trial

  parameter Integer id=Modelica.Math.Random.Utilities.initializeImpureRandom(globalSeed) "A unique number used to sort equations correctly";
  parameter Integer globalSeed=30020 "Global seed to initialize random number generator";

  Real p(start=Modelica.Math.Random.Utilities.impureRandom(id=id));
  Integer E(start=1, fixed=true);

equation 

  when (sample(1, 3600)) then
    //sample(start+interval) ce qui donne "start + i*interval"
    p = Modelica.Math.Random.Utilities.impureRandom(id=id);

    if pre(E) == 1 then
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 2;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 3;
      else
        E = 4;
      end if;

    elseif pre(E) == 2 then
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 1;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 3;
      else
        E = 4;
      end if;

    elseif pre(E) == 3 then
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 1;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 2;
      else
        E = 4;
      end if;

    else
      // if E == 4 
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 1;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 2;
      else
        E = 3;
      end if;
    end if;

  end when;

  annotation (
    Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)),
    Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)),
    experiment(StopTime=86400, __Dymola_Algorithm="Dassl"));
end Trial;

I also corrected:

the declaration of E : Real to Integer + fixed=true,
the conditions depending of the value of E : pre(E) avoids an algebraic loop,
the last if-statement needs to be an else.


If you use impureRandom you should skip dividing by 32767. The reason for the division is to get a number in the interval [0,1] (as rand() returns 0..32767 - whereas impureRandom already returns a real in [0,1].

You're correct. I assumed the function rand() was returning a value beetween 0 and 1 like most random functions do. Besides, you must have posted your answer while I was redacting mine ahah :)

Thank you very much for your answers! Both work well. However, I discovered that the sequence is always the same. Every time the output is the same because the seed is the same, the rand function has the same problem. Do you think there's a way to avoid this and have a new random sequence every time?

There are a number of issues. First the corrected code:
model Trial
  impure function rand
    output Integer i;
    external "C";
  end rand;
  Real p(start=rand()/32767);
  Integer E(start=1);

equation 

when (sample(1,3600)) then//sample(start+interval) ce qui donne "start + i*interval"
    p = rand()/32767;

    if pre(E) == 1 then
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 2;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 3;
      else
        E = 4;
      end if;

    elseif pre(E) == 2 then
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 1;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 3;
      else
        E = 4;
      end if;

    elseif pre(E) == 3 then
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 1;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 2;
      else
        E = 4;
      end if;

    else
      if p < 0.2 then
        E = 1;
      elseif p < 0.6 then
        E = 2;
      else
        E = 3;
      end if;
    end if;

end when;


  annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)), Diagram(
        coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)),
    experiment(StopTime=86400, __Dymola_Algorithm="Dassl"));
end Trial;

Then a list of the changes:

Functions should be declared, in particular functions that don't return Real.
E is an integer, not a Real - that also allows comparison.
Equations in Modelica work differently than algorithms in other languages, use pre(E) to access the previous value of E.
If-statements must end with an else-clause even if they logically exhaust all possibilities (Unless the condition is an evaluable parameter expression.)
Functions that return different values for the same input should be declared as impure.

